# Initialize a numpy sparse matrix efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, adjacency-list

I have an array with m rows and arrays as values, which indicate the index of columns and are bounded to a large number n.
E.g:

```
 Y = [[1,34,203,2032],...,[2984]]
```

Now I want an efficient way to initialize a sparse numpy matrix X with dimensions m,n and values corresponding to Y (X[i,j] = 1, if j is in Y[i], = 0 otherwise).

Comment: What is "a sparse numpy matrix"? Or do you want a _scipy_ matrix, like `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`?

Comment: sorry, I want a matrix like scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.

Comment: The canonical way of making a `coo` matrix is to use the `(data, (i,j))` inputs.  Your `Y` if flattened should work as the `j` parameter.  `data` would an equivalent size array of 1's.  The `i` then needs to be row indices, replicated as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are already close to csr format, so I suggest using that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from itertools import chain

# create an example    
m, n = 20, 10
X = np.random.random((m, n)) < 0.1
Y = [list(np.where(y)[0]) for y in X]

# construct the sparse matrix
indptr = np.fromiter(chain((0,), map(len, Y)), int, len(Y) + 1).cumsum()
indices = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(Y), int, indptr[-1])
data = np.ones_like(indices)    
S = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), (m, n))
# or    
S = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))

# check
assert np.all(S==X)
```